# What does "Our climate is indisposed to favour us even this once" mean?

Tags: meaning

Please help me to understand the meaning of this expression:

> Our climate is indisposed to favour us even this once. (The Cherry Orchard).

What does "even this once" mean in this phrase?

Comment: In English, that would probly be better as _Our climate is not disposed to `VP`_. When you use a negative prefix instead of an independent negative, you lose some flexibility in determining the scope of negation. Mostly _indisposed_ is intransitive and means 'ill or pretending to be ill'; it normally doesn't take an infinitive complement clause like _disposed_ does.

Answer (score 2):

*Indisposed to* here means *not disposed to, unwilling to*.

*Even this once* means *even on this single occasion*.

Epikhodov is a comic figure. As will you learn as you read further, he is given to expressing his  thoughts in exaggeratedly "literary" diction; just five lines after this Dunyasha says of him that

> He's a nice young man, but every now and again, when he begins talking, you can't understand a word he's saying.

And most of what he says is regretful, if not downright melancholy. In this particular case he is complaining that the weather is deliberately making itself unpleasant, despite the fact that an important and potentially festive event is about to take place--the return of the mistress of the estate after a long absence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was born and bred in Russia and I understand Epikhodov's diction well, but I suspect the translator had allowed a petty mistake here. I'm afraid I couldn't put it clear in English. In the original text their's no the meaning "even on this single occasion".

Comment: I envy you. I can read Chekhov only in translation - and the translations are so varied that I have to guess what he actually wrote.

Comment: Don't you think that the phrase "Even this once" sounds confusing to the beginning of the sentence ? And does this phrase usual in English? (you may correct my harsh language a little, if you please)

Comment: @blackbirdfly13 Oh, no, it's ordinary English idiom = "even on this single occasion". *It's our anniversary. Did I get flowers? Of course not. John never gives me flowers, even this once. Bastard.*

Comment: One man from London said me that in this case their's must be "even this instance" instead.

Comment: Finally, please, examine my English in my comments. Just say if I've done the mistakes.

Comment: @blackbirdfly13 A) Your informant is wrong; *even this once* is somewhat colloquial, but it is acceptable in most 'higher' registers, too.  B) 1) put it **clearly**.  2) You confuse *their* (possessive of *they*) with *there* (dummy pronoun, as in "There is not the meaning", and "There must be"). "

Answer (score 1):

```
Climate is indisposed to favor us  --> The weather usually stinks.
Even this once                     --> It stinks right now.
```